# Python Serial: having trouble reading the port

Tags: python, readline, pyserial

I'm attempting to read the values of some GPIO. Here's the code:

```
import serial
import codecs
import time

ser = serial.Serial(port = 'COM4', baudrate = 9600, \
                    parity = serial.PARITY_NONE, \
                    stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE, \
                    bytesize  = serial.EIGHTBITS, \
                    timeout  = 0, \
                     )
print('connected to: ',ser.name)
ser.close()

def SSend(input):
    ser.write(codecs.decode(input, "hex_codec")) #send as ASCII
    print('sent: ', input)

def ReadIO():
    #open the port
    try: 
        ser.open()
    except:
        print('error opening serial port')
        exit()

    #flush the buffers
    ser.flushInput()   
    ser.flushOutput() 

    #write data to read from GPIO 
    #causes SC18IM to return a byte containing each of the 8 I/O values
    SSend(b'4950')   
    time.sleep(0.1) #allow time for the data to be received  


    #read the data
    serialData = False
    serialData = ser.readline()
    ser.close()

    return serialData

while 1:
    print(ReadIO())
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

This prints the following:

sent:
  b'4950'

b''

(I am expecting back either 0x00 or 0x20 instead of an empty byte)

I know my hardware is good as is what I'm sending because it get back what I expect when using Realterm and have successful write commands in my script elsewhere.

I had some luck using this

```
#read the data
serialData = False
for c in ser.readline():
    print('in loop')
    print(c)
    serialData = c
ser.close()
```

However, I don't really understand why it worked and it only appears to work intermittently.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readline()` assumes that there is some end-of-line symbol, like `\n` or `\r`. You should read data byte-wise:

```
serialData = ''
while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
    c=ser.read(1)
# or    c=ser.read(1).decode('latin1')
    serialData += c
```

Comment: Oh, I see now. Thanks for clearing that up. Another part of the problem was that the slave was sending the serial data in ASCII characters, this problem was fixed using `binascii.hexlify(data)`